# Ayuda con xml, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xml

Mi App consta de un `Activity` donde se van cargando los `Fragment`.

En este caso a cargar es `fragment_automotor`, el mismo realiza una busqueda en base a una patente, devuelve los datos del titular y en un `RecyclerView` clasifica la deuda al dia de hoy.

Dicho `fragment` tiene un `LinearLayout` donde al hacer click en un tipo de deuda, se carga dinamicamente un `fragment` (detail_fragment) con el detalle de la misma (esta hecho de esta manera porque ademas de automotor se pueden consultar otras tasas y reutilizo el codigo de este fragment).

Al seleccionar uno o varios comprobantes aparece un boton indicando el monto a pagar y al hacer click redirige al pago.

El problema es que pretendo que este botón se ubique al final de la pantalla y no lo logro, me queda superpuesto a los comprobantes y con espacio blanco por debajo, quizas alguien vea un error que yo no. dejo el xml de los fragment involucrado y una imagen para mayor comprension del problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

fragment_automotor

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radius"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_busqueda"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etBuscarPatente"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Patente"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorGreyDark"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBuscar"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="0.4"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/search"
                    android:theme="@style/RaisedButton" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cardDatos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0.0px"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radius"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Cuenta N°"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtIdCuenta"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Titular"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtTitular"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.3"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Vehículo"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDescripcion"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.7"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Modelo"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtModelo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.4"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:text="Patente"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtPatente"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:padding="3dip"
                        android:textStyle="italic" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvComp1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_contenedor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

MainActivity

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackground">
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_options"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

detail_fragment

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTipoDeudaComprobante"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvCompxTipo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnPagar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_chevron_right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Comment: Hola cual es el id del botón?

Comment: btnPagar es el id. esta ubicado dentro de detail_fragment

Comment: El problema es la propiedad que tiene de layout_alignParentBottom. Remueve esa propiedad del botón y haz lo que dice @Elenasys en su respuesta al problema. Ahora bien, como el tamaño del RecyclerView es wrap_content tienes 2 opciones. O definir un tamaño fijo utilizando weight para asegurar que no será mas grande que el height del Relative, asumiento que es match_parent o agregar un Scrollview al Relative padre. Esto hara que si tu RecyclerView crece demasiado, el botón que se ira hacia debajo de la pantalla, puedas visualizarlo haciendo Scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero agregues la propiedad `android:layout_below="@+id/rvCompxTipo"` para asegurar que el botón siempre se posicione bajo el `RecyclerView`:

```
         <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPagar"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rvCompxTipo"

                ...
                ...
```